# crear archivo yaml a partir de excel

Tags: python, excel, dataframe, yaml

estoy tratando de crear un archivo con extensión .yaml, a partir de os datos de un esquema que viene en excel, estaba intentando llevarlo a un dataframe y luego iterarlo, pero no me funciona dado la estructura de varios campos que son de tipo record o array, anidados en varios niveles, me podrían dar una mano para entender cómo recorrer esta estructura? tenia este código con el que estoy probando:

```
indent = " "
fields = "fields"
fuente = " source:"
setdatos = "dataset:"
name = "name"
key = "  key:"
typee = "     type:"
nullvalue = "true"
null = "    null:"
with open("input_master.yaml", "w") as file:
    for table, group in master.groupby("table"):
        file.write("INPUT:")
        #file.write("\n  - table: {}\n".format(table))
        file.write("\n  - table: {}\n".format(table))
        file.write("\n    ".join("{indent2}{fuente}{indent}{source} \n {indent2}{setdatos}{indent}{dataset} \n {indent2}{fields}:  \n  {indent2} - {name}:{indent}{Field_name} \n {indent2}  {key:}\n{indent2}{typee}{indent}{datatype}  \n {indent2}{null}{indent}{nullvalue}  \n".format(indent2=indent2, indent=indent, table=row.table, fuente=fuente, setdatos=setdatos, source=row.source, dataset=row.dataset, key=key, fields=fields, datatype=row.datatype, null=null, nullvalue=nullvalue, name=name, typee=typee, Field_name=row.Field_name) for row in group.itertuples()))
```

el formato de salida que debo alcanzar es:
[image: formato archivo yaml salida]

el excel de base es:

[image: Excel con esquema]
muchas gracias y cualquier orientación me servirá mucho

Comment: Mi recomendación es que uses una librería de terceros o diseñes de 0 tu propio serializador de yaml.

Comment: Hay varias librerías para serializado a Yaml. En general lo suyo es crear un array con la estructura y luego serializar dicho array a Yaml.

Comment: ¿puedes pegar un enlace a la excel (o a una equivalente) para que pueda hacer pruebas. Copiar todos los datos de una imagen no es divertido :-)